# How do you avoid repeating styles in shadow DOM?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, templatetags

I'm new to web components, so not sure if there's an easy answer or best practice on this one.

If I want to create a series of repeating elements with encapsulated style how do I avoid repeating the style block with each element.

A reduced version of the code I'm using is:

```
<ul id="wrapper"></ul>

<template id="template">
  <style>
    li { color: red }
  </style>

  <li></li>
</template>

<script>
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var tpl = document.getElementById('template');
var shadow = wrapper.createShadowRoot();
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
  tpl.content.querySelector('li').textContent = arr[i];

  var clone = document.importNode(tpl.content, true);

  shadow.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
```

The problem I have with that is that the shadow DOM has a duplicated style block for each `<li>`, and am not sure the best way round it.

I have tried nesting a template and that is either never going to work or I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast-forward to 2022 and we now have "constructable stylesheets".  Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets).  Basically the browser is smart enough to use only a single constructed stylesheet for all those copies of your webcomponent on the page!  :)

Quoting from the article:

> Constructable Stylesheets make it possible to define and prepare shared CSS styles, and then apply those styles to multiple Shadow Roots or the Document easily and without duplication. Updates to a shared CSSStyleSheet are applied to all roots into which it has been adopted

Answer (score 1):

How about checking for a style element and importing it separately?

```html
<ul id="wrapper"></ul>

<template id="template">
  <style>
    li { color: red }
  </style>

  <li></li>
</template>

<script>
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var tpl = document.getElementById('template').cloneNode(true);
var shadow = wrapper.createShadowRoot();

var style = tpl.content.querySelector('style');
if (style) {
  tpl.content.removeChild(style);
  shadow.appendChild(document.importNode(style, true));
}

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
  tpl.content.querySelector('li').textContent = arr[i];
  shadow.appendChild(document.importNode(tpl.content, true));
}
</script>
```